# Find if the string has two slashes and replace it

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe col2, and I want to check if its column "color2" has more than 2 colors.

```
    color2
1   white
2   black/red
3   yellow
4   pink
5   purple/blue/red
```

At the moment, I know how to find if the string contains slash in it, but not sure how to find the string has 2 slashes.

Code:

```
grepl("/", col2$color2)
```

After that, I hope to replace it as "2", like the one below:

```
    color2
1   white
2   black/red
3   yellow
4   pink
5   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to find double slashes and `replace` the values. `.*` allows 0 or more characters between 2 slashes.

```
col2$color2 <- with(col2, replace(color2, grepl("/.*/", color2), 2))

color2
#1     white
#2 black/red
#3    yellow
#4      pink
#5         2
```

---

We can also use `str_count` from `stringr` package to count the number of occurrences of "/" and replace the values using `ifelse`

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(str_count(col2$color2, "/") > 1, "2", col2$color2)

#[1] "white"     "black/red" "yellow"    "pink"      "2"
```